# Jackson: JsonInclude how to add Multiple JsonInclude annotation type

Tags: java, annotations, jackson

How can I tell a class to include only NON_EMPTY and NON_NULL values only, 
Using

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class foo{
    String a;
}
```

is throwing error of duplicate annotation.

Comment: Unfortunately you're stuck, it seems, since `@JsonInclude` only has one value and not an array of it...

Comment: please use it for reference https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/json-include-with-content-attribute.html

Comment: Everything that you need to know about @JsonInclude [here](https://cowtowncoder.medium.com/jackson-tips-filtering-with-jsoninclude-27f08979514c). It's from its author, you can't go wrong  ;-)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

"Null is always considered empty" - [Jackson's site](http://static.javadoc.io/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.7.1/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html#NON_EMPTY)

So the NON_EMPTY rule covers both cases..