# How to use Jackson Include.NON_NULL and Include.NON_EMPTY with the same class in Java?

Tags: java, jackson

I want to use the Jackson annotations `@JsonInclude` for `Include.NON_NULL` and `Include.NON_EMPTY` but I cannot do that:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL, Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class A {
}
```

So how can I add both of them for the same class? Thank you!

Comment: Would that help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23631913/10743176 ?

Comment: For general and more complex include rules see [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62542799/6413377)